# How to convert ajax array of objects into array of arrays

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, angularjs, ajax

I have an ajax call which returns array of objects like this:

[image]

Now, it works fine with my code of parsing it into a table in AngularJS.

I am trying to implement pagination with the table and issue arises that pagination does not work with objects, it has to be an array.

I am not able to convert this array of objects into array of arrays for pagination.

My Ajax call code is:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server/search/searchQuery.php',
            data: {data: 'getData', searchText: id.SearchText , typeOfStudy: qTypeOfStudy , typeOfSpecies: qTypeOfSpecies , typeOfSpeciality: qTypeOfSpeciality },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            dataType:"json"
        }).success(function(data) {
```

It would be great if someone can point to a post or a sample code which can convert it.

I already do json_encode on php side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need this solution:

```
var aData = [];
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'server/search/searchQuery.php',
            data: {data: 'getData', searchText: id.SearchText , typeOfStudy: qTypeOfStudy , typeOfSpecies: qTypeOfSpecies , typeOfSpeciality: qTypeOfSpeciality },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            dataType:"json"
        }).success(function(data) {
      var aData = [];
      for(var k in data){
        aData.push(data[k].id, data[k].primary_authors, data[k].primary_titles, data[k].pub_year);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, while it certainly parses the code, it creates a singular array. I am trying to convert your sample code into an associative (multi-dimensional array).

Comment: I think that the only way to convert this on associative array is convert to object, but you need an array right? You can get an multidimensional positional array using `aData [k] = [data[k].id, data[k].primary_authors, data[k].primary_titles, data[k].pub_year];` on foreach instead of my answer. If you get better solution let me know please.

Comment: It worked for me. Now I just have to add labels to the array so that ng-repeat can parse the data

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, try with:

```
$associateArray = array(
                'name'          => 'Test Data',
                'quantity'      => 1,
                'unit'          => 'ks',
                'unit_price'    => 200
        );
```

> Convert Associated Array to Json Object

```
$JsonObject = json_encode($associateArray);
```

> Convert Json String into Associated Array

```
$SociateArray = json_decode($JsonString, true);
```

Comment: Thanks @PaoIm, I will certainly try to implement your solution as well.